# SharePoint 2013 Anonymous Access Enabled, but Still Promp for Credentials

Tags: 2013, anonymous-authentication, credentials

I am currently building a portal which allow anonymous access in SharePoint 2013. I have configured anonymous access on the web app (via Central Administration), site collection level (Site Settings -> Site Permissions -> Anonymous Access -> Entire Web Site).

But strangely, when I tried to access the portal, it kept showing credentials prompt. But in the credentials prompt, when I click the cancel button, then the yes, the anonymous user could still use the site. When the user access the other page, the credentials prompt was showing up again, but when the cancel button was clicked, then the user could still see the page.

I have tried other solutions, like deactivating the limited access user permission lockdown feature in Site Collection Features and disable the ViewFormPagesLockdown Feature via PowerShell. I also had checked that the pages and assets are all published, and the Anonymous Authentication in IIS was also enabled. I tried to add the site to trusted site zone in the browser (IE), and tried to access it from other browser like Chrome or FireFox, but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. :)

Comment: Use Fiddler to get more information, which site is requesting the login. Example: You may have placed a user-picture on your SharePoint site. This picture comes from the MySite, so the MySite-WebApplication will ask credentials.

Comment: Finally going with restoring the last backup (from the day before I configured the anonymous access), reconfigure the anonymous access, and it worked. Strange because the steps are exactly the same with the previous problematic configuration (exactly same steps with the document I've created before).